# Get post from Category by Priority

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, wp-query, get-posts

I want get 3 posts from event custom post type. But i want to do that by category priority. If "featured" category has 3 upcoming event then i want to show 3 posts from it, if "featured" category doesn't have 3 upcoming events then i want to get posts from other category+posts without any category too.

The end result will return 3 upcoming event. I'm a little confuse about how can i add that condition parameter on WP_Query.

Current code(that only return maximum 3 posts from featured category)-

```
$events_args = array(
      'post_type'     => 'ctc_event',                
      'meta_query' => array(
        array(
          'key' => '_ctc_event_end_date',
          'value' => date_i18n( 'Y-m-d' ),
          'compare' => '>=',
          'type' => 'DATE'
        ),
      ),
      'meta_key'      => '_ctc_event_start_date_start_time',
      'meta_type'     => 'DATETIME',
      'orderby'     => 'meta_value',
      'order'       => 'ASC',
      'posts_per_page' => 3,
      'tax_query' => array(
          array(
              'taxonomy' => 'ctc_event_category',
              'field'    => 'slug',
              'terms'    => 'featured',
          ),
      ),
    );

$events = new WP_Query( $events_args );
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can first get posts from your featured category and check if it has any posts or not. If yes, you will show them.

If not, you will make another query that will get 3 posts from random categories (as you described) and show them.

```
$events_args = array(
            // include the code in your question here 
);
$events = new WP_Query( $events_args );
if ($events->have_posts()){
     while ($events->have_posts()) : the_post();
          // your loop code here
     endwhile;
} 
if ((3-($events->found_posts)) > 0) {
     wp_reset_postdata();
     $remaining = 3 - ($events->found_posts);
     $random_args = array(
         // your desired array of attributes, set 'posts_per_page' to $remaining
     );
     $random_posts = new WP_Query($random_args);
     while ($random_posts->have_posts()) : the_post();
         // your loop code here
     endwhile;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But when featured category has less than 3 posts then i need to get remaining posts from other category & show all. How can i do that? Example- featured category has 2 upcoming events but i want to show 3 events total, so i need to take 1 more event from other category & show 3 events(2 from featured category & 1 from other).

Comment: Hi, i updated the code for you.